# Stackexchange.Redis ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect() does does nothing on failed connect?

Tags: redis, booksleeve, stackexchange.redis

I attempt to connect to my Redis Serverinstance through `ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect("127.0.0.1");` but despite no server being up and running the connect does not throw an error nor raise any `ConnectionFailed` event. I double checked I do not have any stand-alone instance nor Windows Service of Redis running.

How can I check whether a connect was successful or not? I run on .Net 4.5 and use StackExchange.Redis version 4.0.30319

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That should probably be logged as a bug on SE.Redis rather than as a question here. It is not meant to do that unless you have have explicitly set `AbortOnConnectFail` to `false` (it defaults to `true`).

As for how to detect it if a glitch exists:

- try a `Ping()`
- use the `IsConnected` property on `IServer`
- use the `IsConnected(RedisKey)` method on `IDatabase` (if you aren't using a cluster, you can pass `default(RedisKey)` to that method; on a cluster it is necessary to know *which server* you are talking about)

Comment: The server is not connected per IsConnected property. Is it intended behavior to not reflect the failure to connect upon calling `ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect(endPointAddress)`? If not would you know when a fix makes it into the next release and when to expect the next release? Thanks

Comment: @MattWolf yes, it is *intended* that `Connect`/`ConnectAsync` would fail if it cannot connect, *unless* you have disabled `AbortOnConnectFail`; I have a repro - will look later today

Comment: @MattWolf this is now pushed in 1.0.241

Comment: @MarcGravell, can you please check related to redis http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24531421/remove-delete-all-one-item-from-stackexchange-redis-cache