# Why isn't DeleteKey working, for Azure RedisCache?

Tags: azure, redis, azure-redis-cache

I'm using Azure RedisCache, and when I call the following command:

```
_cache.KeyDelete(key, CommandFlags.HighPriority)
```

The key is not deleted and there are no errors.

Similarly, nor does the following work if a key/value is already set:

```
_cache.StringSet(dataKey, "")
_cache.KeyExpire(dataKey, DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(-2), CommandFlags.HighPriority)
```

Comment: What's the SDK you're using?

Comment: Le-roy Staines - Is the answer provided was helpful for you ? if so could you please accept the answer (click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in) as solution for your ask. This could be beneficial to other community members.

Answer (score 0):

> Make Sure you enable `allowAdmin=true` in the config string or `Configuarationoptions`

You may checkout the [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24531421/remove-delete-all-one-item-from-stackexchange-redis-cache) thread addressing similar issue.